# Testing antenna without anechoic chamber or RF foam absorber

Tags: rf, antenna, emc, radiation, vna

I have to test an inset-fed microstrip antenna operating at 2.4 GHz. My objective is to measure S11 and the radiation pattern. The problem is I cannot count on an anechoic chamber or microwave absorbers as they fall out of my budget. I am using a NanoVNA, so that could also be a limitation. (I am also interested in hearing anyone's opinions on this device for this application if they have used it.)

How big of a problem could my current setup be when characterizing the antenna, particularly for the radiation pattern?

Are there any cheaper RF absorbers that could be useful in mitigating reflections?

Alternatively, what recommendations could you give me to build the setup for characterizing the antenna?

Answer (score 1):

Use the "poor person's anechoic chamber": outdoors. Get the device under test up off the ground using foam blocks. This will be adequate for measuring S11.

For the radiation pattern, make angle calibration marks on the block just under the device so you can manually rotate the device for each measurement. Measure the radiation pattern using RSSI when transmitting to, or receiving from, a similar device in the far field (more than 10 times the wavelength and 10 times the size of the antenna). With a typical microstrip antenna at 2.4 Ghz you only need to be a few meters away to satisfy this condition.

Comment: Even the rich people do this sometimes. MITRE corp in Bedford Massachusetts has a large outdoor antenna test field.

Comment: @JohnDoty Yes indeed, I worked at a govt contractor on the opposite coast with 100 ft towers for this purpose. But that had to work down to 100 MHz.

Comment: Depending on what part of the country you live, space in the outdoors may not be the "poor person's anechoic chamber." :)

Answer (score 1):

Been there, done that, for a 70 cm CubeSat antenna.

Go outdoors. The Universe is nicely anechoic. I worked on wooden tables on a wooden deck. Watch out for common mode conduction on your cables (I used snap-on chokes to block it).

Do plenty of control experiments. Try simple antennas whose characteristics you think you understand. Verify that when you double the distance between the antenna under test and your reference antenna, you see 6 dB less signal. These will give you an idea of how trustworthy your measurements are.

a NanoVNA is not a super-accurate lab instrument: you won't get 0.1 dB accuracy. It is, however, good enough for most practical purposes. You won't actually *use* an antenna in a perfect environment, so your real performance will vary anyway.